# How to wget mirror website faster?

Tags: wget, mirror, httrack

when I use `wget -m url` it downloads one file at a time.

How to make `wget` download multiple files at a time?

Comment: Looks like [wget download with multiple simultaneous connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430810/wget-download-with-multiple-simultaneous-connections). Also check the first comment in the question above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To mirror a website you use a [web crawler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler). `wget` (with the `-m` flag) is listed but `wget` is not designed to do parallel downloads. `aria2` on the other hand cannot crawl a website, but downloads a list of urls. You have to know the url list at the start.

You need a tool that can do both. [In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430810/wget-download-with-multiple-simultaneous-connections) there is the suggestion to use [httrack](http://www.httrack.com/): `httrack url` will mirror `url` with 8 simultaneous connections.

Answer (score 5):

There are scripts like `theripper.sh` ([link to repo](https://github.com/kajeagentspi/Datahoarder)), which combine the use of `wget` as a spider and `aria2c` as a multi-thread downloader.

But the simple answer is to use `wget2`.
There is a [repo](https://github.com/rockdaboot/wget2) from which you can clone it and build, or you might easily install it with `sudo apt install wget2`. The usage is almost the same as with `wget`, but you get more options which should do the job:

```
--max-threads         Max. concurrent download threads.
                          (default: 5)
```